# Architecture which allow communication between parts of the system

Tags: events, design-patterns, architecture, event-handling

This question is about architecture.
Actually, I want to know which architecture patterns or solution allow doing the following.

For example, I have a customer, the customer could subscribe to news on my site. I need a solution that will allow me to send a notification to all subscribed customers when new news added. And of course, I want to do it automatically without adding additional code to news adding.

But, it could be plenty of some tasks. Not only send a notification when some news added.
*And it will be brilliant if someone could suggest something which is not Observer, and event or message sourcing.*

Comment: Check out the observer-pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observer pattern is great if there are only one publisher.

Pub/Sub is better since you subscribe on a specific message, since anyone can publish a message. A message could be something called `NewsPublished` which contains all relevant details about the news item being published.

As for implementation it depends on if you are looking for a in-process solution or if you want two or more processes being able to communicate.

If .NET and inprocess is the requirement I would use an inversion of control container to find all subscribers.

Comment: You mean that publisher post message to some queue (for example MSMQ) and then handler which handle this queue run message handler. Is  understand general idea well?

Comment: MSMQ is a specific implementation. Pub/Sub has a lot of different implementations. You could also use a service bus like nServiceBus or create an inprocess implementation.

Comment: Actually this topic start because i know, that this task is possible to solve with ServiceBus, but i think that for my current needs it's like break a butterfly on the wheel and I curious - is it possible to more simple solution.

Comment: I've made one for inprocess which uses IoC: https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/wiki/Domain-events

Comment: All code exits on that page an are available as nuget packages. The dispatcher implementation: https://github.com/sogeti-se/Sogeti.Pattern/blob/master/source/Sogeti.Pattern/Sogeti.Pattern.Core/DomainEvents/ServiceResolverDispatcher.cs

Comment: As I see - the main logic is encapsulated in ServiceResolverDispatcher. It gets instance from type and invokes handler method. Is there is common way of work for ServiceBuses?

Comment: It's not a service bus. It's a message publisher. Service buses are mostly for communication between applications while my dispatcher is for communication within an application.

Comment: OK, sorry, my mistake. But I need to know one thing, how it possible to release from 
DomainEventDispatcher.Current.Dispatch(new UserCreated(user)); For example use some listener who will be listen all event and call handler for them

Comment: It's done automagically as long as the listener is registered in the IoC.

Comment: Could you describe this process to me in more details or provide some links where I could read about it?

Comment: Google "Inversion Of Control" and then start to use my favorite autofac ;)

Comment: I know whot autofac is, but I use StructureMap or Unity. It intresting for me - is IoC container listen which object created and if event created somehow call hendler for it? Sorry for many question, I just want to understand background principals

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8127/discussion-between-jgauffin-and-ph0en1x)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, Observer pattern seems like the right pattern for the job.

Example: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx#_self1

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I second (or rather fourth) the observer pattern.

If you happen to code under .NET, take a look at the powerful [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) (Reactive Extensions) framework!

According to the website, it "is a library to compose asynchronous and event-based programs using observable collections and LINQ-style query operators."

Comment: Don't second or fourth. Vote on another answer.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123369/flagged-incorrect-answer-got-declined).